# Snapping to currently digitized feature using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, snapping

In QGIS 3.14 there's a new feature "Snapping to the currently digitized feature". This feature is demonstrated within a gif on the QGIS website (also shown below).

How can this feature be fully utilized?

Such as...

- How can the 90-degree angles be displayed?
- How can the curser position and angle be displayed?
- How to properly use the "Alt + A" function?

I've been searching for a tutorial on how to use this feature, and I've had no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CAD-like digitizing tools are activated via View > Panels > Advanced Digitizing panel > Enable advanced digitizing tools

Angles for the cursor to stick are selected by clicking the 'gear button' on the Advanced digitizing panel.

Cursor position indication is activated by the 'Toggle floater' button of the same panel.

Not sure, if this is proper use of the Alt+A, but it seems that it locks the current angle of the line projected from the point, so you can slide along that angle without losing it.

And the 'snapping to the currently digitized feature' can be enabled from the snapping toolbar and from the project snapping settings.

Answer (score 1):

This video is also very helpful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsjmLa16obs